# Need the specific command to get a particular value from df command

Tags: python

I am running a python script to get few commands to get executed on a remote aix server. The command is to get the size of a file system.

command : `df -g | grep -w /`

output :

`/dev/hd4           0.94      0.87    8%     3865     2% /`

I only want 0.87 as output which is the third column of output. I want to extract the value in a variable but grep will give me a scalar value. Please let me know how can I format this command to do what i intend to do.

Comment: Is the goal to get the value into a python program? If so, have you looked into `subprocess`?

Comment: no i have not looked into subprocess, yet..and yes, i want to get the value in python program

Comment: Don't know about Python, in shell it would be something like this: `Val=$(ssh user@host 'df -g | grep -w /' | (read _ _ X _; echo $X))` -- edit: fixed a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) with `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output(["df -g | grep -w /"], shell=True).split()[2])
```

`.split()` splits the return into the separate values, and then `[2]` gets the value that you want.